# sqlplus on ubuntu, error: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I followed https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-install-sqlplus/
I had downloaded the 21 versions from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

I am getting this error:
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

in my instantclient_21_3 folder, it doesn't even have sq1 msb files. I have set the ORACLE_PATH to instantclient directory.
Where I can get these msb files?

Comment: Do you just have ~6 files in that directory? The [download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) mentions this, but you also need one of the BASIC packages installed as well. The SQL*Plus package by itself does not contain all of the necessary code.

Comment: the instantclient_21_3 has 37 files which came from instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip

Comment: @kfinity, I believe you meant to say that *Instant Client package does not contain SQL Plus*.

Comment: right. based on the above instructions link, it came from a different rpm which is: oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-21.3.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm 
This also did not contain msb files

Comment: There is a virtual file system in one of the .so's that contains "files" like the *.msb files.  So don't worry that you are missing any message files.  Don't set ORACLE_PATH or ORACLE_HOME. Review the installation instructions on the download page.  The Ubuntu instruction link is old.  The 19c & 21c Instant Client RPMs already setup and run ldconfig for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can install like:

```
alien -i --scripts oracle-instantclient19.13-basic-19.13.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
alien -i --scripts oracle-instantclient19.13-sqlplus-19.13.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
apt-get install libaio1
```

You don't need to (i.e shouldn't) set environment variables or run ldconfig.

This will also work with 21c.